# Memory error when using logistic regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I have an array with the shape 57159x924 which I will use as training data. 896 of these 924 columns are feature and the remaining labels. I want to use logistic regression on this, but when I use the fit function from logistic regression I get a memory error. I guess it is because it's too much data for my computer's memory to handle. Is there any way to get around this problem?

The code I want to use is

```
lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=1)
lr.fit(train_set, train_label)
lr.predict_proba(x_test)
```

And the following is the error

> line 21, in main
>       lr.fit(train_set, train_label)
>
> ....
>
> return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>   MemoryError

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would much help if the code was standalone so that anyone willing could run it and immediately try to debug it. Could you please provide such an example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Comment: @sophros the dataset is sadly not public, but would it help to have all the code anyway? The only things I've done this far is to open the file and divide it into test/train, so it's quite basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given enough details to really understand the problem or give a definite answer, but here are a few options I hope will help:

1. The amount of memory available might be configurable.
2. Training over *all* the data at the same time would raise OOM problems in many contexts, which is why the common practice is to use SGD (stochastic gradient descent) by training over batches, i.e. introducing only subsets of the data every iteration and getting a global optimization solution in a stochastic sense. If I'm guessing correctly, you're using [sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), which has different "solvers". Maybe the `saga` solver will handle your situation better.
3. There are other implementations out there, and some of them definitely have batching options built-in in a highly configurable way. And if worst comes to worst, implementing a logistic-regression model is fairly simple, and then you can batch easy as pie.

---

Edit (due to discussion in comments):
Here's a practical way to go about it, with a very very simple (and easy) example -

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
import numpy as np
import random

X1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=[10, 5], cov = np.diag([3, 8]), size=1000)  # diagonal covariance for simplicity
Y1 = np.zeros((1000, 1))

X2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=[-4, 55], cov = np.diag([5, 1]), size=1000)  # diagonal covariance for simplicity
Y2 = np.ones((1000, 1))

X = np.vstack([X1, X2])
Y = np.vstack([Y1, Y2]).reshape([2000,])

sgd = SGDClassifier(loss='log', warm_start=True)  # as mentioned in answer. note that shuffle is defaulted to True.
sgd.partial_fit(X, Y, classes = [0, 1])  # first time you need to say what your classes are

for k in range(1000):
    batch_indexs = random.sample(range(2000), 20)
    sgd.partial_fit(X[batch_indexs, :], Y[batch_indexs])
```

In practice you should be looking at the loss and accuracy and using a suitable `while` instead of `for`, but that much is left for the reader ;-)

Note that you can control more than I've shown (like the number of iterations etc.), so you should read the documentation of [SGDClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) properly.
Another thing to note is that there are different practices of batching. I just took a random subset every iteration, but some prefer to make sure every point in the data has been seen an equal amount of times (e.g. shuffle the data and then take batches in order indexes or something).

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details, is it anything in particular you want to know? I'm quite new to data science (and python), but to implement the SGD is it just to write " > clf = SGDClassifier(loss="log", penalty="l2") >clf.fit(train_set, train_label) " ? Or do I need to take anything else into account? Because by using these lines of code I only got the same error.

Comment: Nothing is ever (in my opinion) just "a matter of writing these lines of code". It's about understanding what the lines of code do and using them correctly.  
To your specific point, sklearn's SGDClassifer is one option, and using the log-loss will indeed train a logistic regression classification model. But in order to use the mini-batches I described, you need to use `warm_start=True`, alongside `partial_fit` (and the necessary loop-ing of course) as well.  If this helps, let me know and I'll integrate it into my answer.

Comment: It makes sense, so you should probably intergrate it in your answer. Sadly I'm way too bad at coding to be able to implement it correctly, but thank you for the help

Comment: Updated with a simplistic example as well

Comment: Oops. This time the example has batches as well :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the example. I triend to implement it, but it crashes as soon as I get to `sgd.partial_fit(X, Y, classes = [0, 1])` and says that it's the memory again. Moreover, how do I determine the numbers in range(2000,20) on line 18?

Comment: At this point one would need to actually reproduce the problem in order to debug it. The numbers are just for the random sampling: `2000` data-points, `range(2000)` is the list of indexes I'd like to randomly sample from, `20` is the sample size. simple inputs to the `random.sample` method. Try using a batch size of one, try a different environment, try running memory queries to break things down, you know, regular debugging stuff. I said before hand that there are multiple points to check and there's only so much guess work one can do from this (conceptual and practical) distance.